# Django: Tuple choices with integers not working in template

Tags: python, django

I have a few choices like so in my Django models:

```
lead = 'Lead'
contact = 'Contact'
CHOICES = (
    (lead, 0),
    (contact, 1)
)
```

When using an if statement to display an object property in the template then it doesn't work (however doesn't display any errors):

```
{% if object.choice == 0 %}
    {{ object.choice }} # This doesn't display anything
{% endif %}
```

However, the following does work:

```
{% if object.choice == 'Lead' %}
    {{ object.choice }} # This works
{% endif %}
```

Even when I switch the choices (like `(lead, 'Lead')`) then only the `== 'Lead'` works and not the `== 0`

Why does this not work with integers and only with strings? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the value as an integer in the database, then you need to swap the order of your choice tuples.

```
CHOICES = (
    (0, "Lead"),
    (1, "Contact")
)
```

With this change, `object.choice` will be `0` or `1`, and you can use `{{ object.get_choice_display }}` to display `Lead` or `Contact` in the template.

Comment: In the admin, this gave an error of 'Select a valid choice. 0 is not one of the available choices.' after I migrated the changes.

Comment: I can't tell why you would get that error message from the info you have given in your question. If the model field is a `CharField` instead of an `IntegerField`, then perhaps you need to change it to an `IntegerField`, or use `"0"` and `"1"`.